# Regex returning unexpectedly

Tags: regex

Why is this returning as a match?

- should match: "One warm day"
- should not match: "The warmest day";

.

```
$str = "One warm day";
$r = "/warm\s*(day)*/i";
echo "STR: $str<br>";
echo "REGEX: $r<br>";
if(preg_match($r,$str)){
    echo "match";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the whitespaces and "day" is optional, you may have to specify an end of line:

```
/warm\s*(day)*$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `*` quantifier meaning (`0` or more times) from your capturing group.

```
/warm\s*(day)/i
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lX8uT1)